# Enable android hotspot from ubuntu

Tags: networking, bluetooth, android

On a mac I can enable the hotspot on my iphone if I need to. The iphone will then enable a hotspot, and the mac connects to it like a regular wifi-network.

Is there a similar feature in ubuntu for connecting to an android phone without having to manually enable the hotspot on my phone?

The fallback is of course to share internet from the phone over bluetooth, which works fine, but the bandwidth is limited over bluetooth.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Keep in mind that your Mac and your iPhone run the same operating system by the same manufacturer, who is famous for having its devices talk to each other.  Given that your Ubuntu computer and your Android phone are not by the same manufacturer, I don't think you can expect the same functionality.  You can, of course, turn your Android's phone Hotspot on manually -- I think that's your real fallback before Bluetooth...no?